# I am trying to display data grid from Visual Studio with SQL Server

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

I am trying to display data grid from SQL Server with Visual Studio and I have this error shown in the screenshot. I have tried everything here and did not find any answers please see that screenshot. Thank you

[that is the photo with the error]

Comment: I can't see the photo and pasting some code would also help.

Comment: Hi, thank you for letting us know.I will try to upload it again or paste the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing web apps , go to web.config file add below , change parameter according your SQL environment setup.

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>  
            <add name="PSDatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=YourSQLserverName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
....
```

then built a class file , let say we name it as "ClassSQL" and then built a sub method that able get data from SQL server using TSQL

```
 public static DataTable RunSQL_DML_FillDataGrid(string TSQL)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PSDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


        try
        {
            // Run TSQL on SQL server
            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(TSQL, connectionString);

            // MS Term ' Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
            // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
            // update the database.

            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            // Populate a new data table and return the table.
            // MS Term ' Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            return table;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Finally call the class method from your main code and bind it to grid view

```
string TSQL = "select * from TableA";
DataTable dt =ClassSQL.RunSQL_DML_FillDataGrid(TSQL);

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

You can use this on other application type ( console , desktop , MVC) as well , or as a direct function , as long as you tweak a bit some of the code.

Comment: Please marked it as answer ( click  ▲ )  if it do help , thanks you :)